# Display pdf in browser for ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdf

I want to show pdf ajax response in browser.Problem is I can not directly open the url as pdf is created dynamically how can I show it.

```
$.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                    complete: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        window.open("pdf.php","_blank");

                    }
                });
```

PDF response is

```
%PDF-1.3
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/Resources 2 0 R
/Contents 4 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 1265>>
```

PHP code

```
 header('Cache-Control: public');
 header('Content-type: application/pdf');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="new.pdf"');  
 header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($data));
 echo $data;
```

Any help should be appreciated.

Comment: Just open the new window to start...Post the data to the new window.

Comment: What kind of error do you have? What happens if you put pdf.php to the browser's address bar directly? If it works then JS should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your pdf.php

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
```

Comment: Your problem is in the pdf.php file. Add the relevant code of this file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I will give you the solution ... I hope it solves your problem.

When you call your service, you should ask for a `dataType: 'binary'` response. Then, use `saveAs`([FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)) to trigger the download.

But, $.ajax doesn't let you download binary content out of the box, it will try to decode your binary from UTF-8 and corrupt it. Either use a jQuery plugin to solve this problem [jquery.binarytransport.js](https://github.com/henrya/js-jquery/tree/master/BinaryTransport)

exemplo:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $("form#data").attr("action"),
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'binary',     //--> using jquery.binarytransport.js
    success: function (response) {
        // Default response type is blob
        saveAs(response, "test.pdf"); //--> using FileSaver.js
    }
});
```

Good look! :)